# Best way to make class variables initialization mandatory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some class variables that should be defined before any class instance created. It doesn't have default value, only someone who will use that class can init it.

I do following:

```
class Foo:
    _inited = False  # flag to show if Foo.static_init was called
    _FILE_PATH = None  # this var should be inited before class using

    @classmethod
    def static_init(cls, file_path):
        cls._inited = True
        cls._FILE_PATH = file_path

    def __init__(self):
        if not Foo._inited:
            raise Exception('Foo.static_init should be called first.')
```

It looks ugly, any way to do static init better?

Comment: You could make `Foo` private and then return the class `Foo` from a function that expects `file_path`.

Comment: why not use constructor initialization? or didn't i get your question, you can so force the user to provide initial data?

Comment: I think your current implementation looks decent, and not ugly at all.

Comment: perhaps `def init(self, filepath=None): if self._FILE_PATH is None and filepath is None: raise Exception('...)` would be better

Comment: user1767754, I want to init class variable once in config file and not to pass it everywhere I create class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go original way, but make solution reusable. This class decorator can be used to make `cls.static_init()` call mandatory.

```
def static_init(cls_to_decorate):
    class Wrapper(cls_to_decorate):
        _static_init_called = False

        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            if not Wrapper._static_init_called:
                raise Exception('{}.static_init() should be called.'.format(cls_to_decorate.__name__))
            return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

        @classmethod
        def static_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            Wrapper._static_init_called = True
            return super().static_init(*args, **kwargs)
    return Wrapper
```

Usage:

```
@static_init
class Foo:
    _PARAM = None

    def test(self):
        print(Foo._PARAM)

f = Foo()  #Exception: Foo.static_init() should be called.
```

.

```
@static_init
class Foo:
    _PARAM = None

    @classmethod
    def static_init(cls, param):
        cls._PARAM = param

    def test(self):
        print(Foo._PARAM)


Foo.static_init('param')
f = Foo()
f.test()  # param
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to have is a type `Foo` that depends on a value `file_path`.  However, I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want, as you might be having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

One could do so using a definition like this:

```
def make_Foo(file_path):

    class Foo:
        _FILE_PATH = file_path

        def __init__(self):
            pass

    return Foo
```

In this form, the user cannot obtain the type `Foo` without providing the `file_path` argument.  To use such a class one would do this:

```
Foo = make_Foo("/var/tmp")
my_foo = Foo()
```

This has the additional advantage that users can obtain multiple instantiations of the type `Foo` by providing different values of `file_path`:

```
Foo2 = make_Foo("/var/log")
Foo3 = make_Foo("/home")
```

If you want to use the *instantiated* version of `Foo` everywhere in your project, then you can just add `Foo = make_Foo(...)` in some shared module.

Comment: imo, this is far worse than his current solution.

Comment: Say he has another class variable, and he'd like to define that one before he defines the required variable for instance. With this solution, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @SteinarLima: Can you elaborate on the scenario you're describing?

Comment: `class A: optional=None; required=None` I get access to optional first, and want to define `A.optional` before I know what `A.required` shall be.

Comment: `optional = ...; required = some_func(optional); Foo = make_Foo(required, optional=optional)` I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's not possible to define to class inside a function call. I'm just saying it's a lot less extensible and it doesn't do it better than his original solution at all.